# react-navigation: Include a Component in each screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using a `StackNavigator` with `redux` like below. What is the cleanest way to include a `Component` to all my screens? I've tried adding a child `Component` to both `AppWithNavigationState` and `AppNavigator` with no luck.

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <AppWithNavigationState />
</Provider>

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Main: { screen: Main },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  }
})


const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, router }) => {
  return(
    <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: router })} />
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add a sibling component rather than adding a child component. Try the example below.

**Example**

```
const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, router }) => {
  return(
    <View>
        <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: router })} />
        <DefaultComponentForEachScreen />
    </View>
  )
};
```